# Screen Sharing option missing on minimal installation+vino

Tags: screen, vnc, sharing, 21.10, vino

I have a fresh install of 21.10 and selected the minimal installation as this will mostly be a hands off machine and I don't need the majority of the extras. This of course does not install vino so I installed this. However the Sharing tab in setting does not show the slider for screen sharing.

I have tried both the Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu with Xorg and this does not help.

Is there something else I need to do in order to show the slider and allow me to enable screen sharing?

Answer (score 1):

OK so vino is deprecated and Ubuntu has moved to gnome-remote-desktop. After installing this package all works as it should.

I also reported this to Ubuntu who accepted it as a bug in the installer as remote desktop should be installed in a minimal install. It was scheduled to go out in the next release.